# ElasticBeanstalkがVPN経由でアクセスできない

Tags: aws, vpn, vpc

表記について教えてください。
Elasticbeanstalkをプライベートサブネットに設置したものの、VPN（自宅）経由でアクセスができない状態にあります（インスタンスは問題なく生成できる）。
当方の環境は

[自宅]
192.168.11.0/24のセグメント
AWS VPCに対しVPNで接続

[AWS]
CIDR 192.168.112.0/20
プライベートサブネット1 192.168.112.0/24 →RHEL1台設置（192.168.112.10）
プライベートサブネット2 192.168.114.0/24 →Postgres(RDS)１台設置（192.168.114.224）
プライベートサブネット3 192.168.115.0/24 →ElasicBeanstalk(rails)設置（192.168.115.174※インスタンス自動付与)
パブリックサブネット1 192.168.116.0/24 →NATゲートウェイ設置（192.168.115.0/24のサブネットにNATゲートウェイのルートテーブルを割り付け）

事象ですが、
・自宅設置のマシン（192.168.11.21）からEB（192.168.115.174)にアクセスできない
・RHEL（192.168.112.10）からはEB(192.168.115.174)にアクセスできる

要件として、EBはプライベートサブネットに設置することが必須（外部からのアクセスは拒否したいため）。
なので、自宅からEBに対し、NATゲートウェイを経由してのアクセスを考えていましたが事象のとおりです。
ただ、
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-other-services
を確認してみたところ、「VPN 接続〜を経由して NAT ゲートウェイにトラフィックをルーティングすることはできません。NAT ゲートウェイは、これらの接続の他方の側にあるリソースからは使用できません。」のとおり、今回の事象はこの制限に引っかかっているのかなと思いました。

そこで質問ですが、EBはVPNを経由したアクセスは不可能なのでしょうか。もし、NATゲートウェイ以外の方法（NATインスタンス？）でアクセス可能であれば方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず、自己解決しました。この手段がAWS的？にベストプラクティスなのかはわかりませんが、192.168.112.0/24に設置したRHELにリバースプロキシ（Apache）を導入し、EBにリダイレクトする方法をとれば自宅からのアクセスが問題なくできました。
当方の環境では、DNSの名前解決が自宅とAWSで整合性をとらなければいけなかったのですがなんとなりました。

Answer (score 0):

さらに自己レスになります。
EB再起動（廃棄→生成）時にIPが変わってしまうため、リバースプロキシはAutoScale時に対応できないことがわかりました。よって別の手段を模索しました。
結論としては、ELBを使えです。これであれば、本要件も満たせることがわかりました。
EBとELBをプライベートセグメントに設置（セグメントは分ける）し、EB設置のセグメントにNATゲートウェイを設置しました。